# vertical-align with inline elements

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                height: 300px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: aqua;     
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }           
            div > span {                
                vertical-align: middle;
                background-color: orange;               
                font-size: 3em;
            }    
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <div>           
            <span>Hello!</span>
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

In the image below, **Actual** is what the *HTML* above renders, and **Expected** is the layout I need.

[image: HTML Layout]

Is the CSS property `vertical-align` supposed to work this way?

**Edit** :

This question is not a duplicate, I'm trying to understand the behavior of `vertical-align: middle` with `inline` elements. In the case above, keeping or removing the above property value has no effect on the HTML layout.

**Edit2** : 
The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/) under the heading "**A more versatile approach**" presented in the top answer of the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458) question suggested in the comments presents a different layout in my browser. I'm running Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit).

Here's a snaphsot of how it looks in my browser (different from what it looks on the demo link):

In the image below, the `span` element is glued to the top.

[image]

Comment: See [Vertical align not working on inline-block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35529582/1529630) to know **why** `vertical-align: middle` doesn't center at the middle of the containing block, and [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458/1529630) to know **how** you can do it instead.

Comment: About your 2nd edit, I can't reproduce that neither on Firefox 47 nor Chromium 50. If you really can reproduce that, and want to know if it was a bug, if it has been fixed, etc. better ask a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vertical-align` aligns the inline elements with each other, it doesn't position them within their container.

So if for example you have a taller `vertical-align: middle` inline element in the same `div`, the "Hello" will be centred relative to it:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div > span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.big {
  font-size:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello!</span>
  <span class="big">B</span>
</div>
```

There are several techniques for centring text vertically in a container but this is not one - see [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x0gc91ch/1/

add `line-height: 300px`

to the div css, because you are trying to align to the middle of the default line-height, which isn't as tall as your parent div.