# Centering icon with vertical-align in inline-block

Tags: css, sass

I don't understand why `vertical-align: middle` makes an icon not being centered, but a little lower.

HTML:

```
<ul class="operatorscreen__buttons">
  <li class="operatorscreen__single-button">
    <a class="operatorscreen__link button-link button-block button-link_outline" href="#">First icon</a>
  </li>
  <li class="operatorscreen__single-button">
    <a class="operatorscreen__link button-link button-block button-link_outline" href="#">Second</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

scss:

```
.operatorscreen {
    &__single-button {
      &:first-child {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    }

    &__link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;

    &:before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      width: 16px;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 100px;
      margin-right: 12px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-color: red;
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, a red background is little lower than text, though it should be right in the center vertically.

Comment: you think it's lower but it's in the center. Use letters like `jpq` and you will see that it's centred

Comment: You're wrong, it's actually lower, even if i use lowercase letters as first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```css
li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: sub;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First icon</li>
  <li>Second icon</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: sub` does the trick, but i never saw it before.

Comment: but why, sub is supposed to work with sub element that is lowered

Answer (score 1):

When I use a ruler to measure, it looks like `vertical-align: middle` is behaving correctly: it is in the middle of the lower case letters.

If you want it to be "perfect" then you may need to be more precise. There are many ideas, one quick one being:

```
position: relative;
top: -1px; // adjust to your desire
```

More on vertical-align of inline elements here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

Comment: I usually used relative position either, but is it ok to do that? Seems hacky for me.

Comment: Yes, it is a hack because it is not something you can standardise for re-use across different icons. If you ask me, I don't think it looks bad how you have it. Depending on the actual icon you use, it will look more or less aligned anyway due to the shape of the icon / negative space. I would normally do it exactly as you already have done, using `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: Great, thats 'superscript', which makes text appear half a character above the normal line. Glad it solved your query! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually in the middle but you need to know what is the middle.

> Aligns the middle of the element with **the baseline plus half the x-height** of the parent.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_for_inline_elements)</sup>

Here is an illustration to show the middle of the element aligned with the baseline plus half the `x-height`.

```css
.operatorscreen__single-button:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.operatorscreen__link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: 
    /*plus half x-height*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 calc(16px - 0.5ex)/100% 1px no-repeat,
    /*the baseline*/
    linear-gradient(#000,#000)0 16px/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.operatorscreen__link:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="operatorscreen__buttons">
  <li class="operatorscreen__single-button">
    <a class="operatorscreen__link button-link button-block button-link_outline" href="#">First icon</a>
  </li>
  <li class="operatorscreen__single-button">
    <a class="operatorscreen__link button-link button-block button-link_outline" href="#">Second</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your particular case, use `top` (or `text-top`, `text-bottom`, `sub`) instead of `middle` and you will be closer to the *middle* you expect:

```css
.operatorscreen__single-button:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.operatorscreen__link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(#000,#000)center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.operatorscreen__link:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="operatorscreen__buttons">
  <li class="operatorscreen__single-button">
    <a class="operatorscreen__link button-link button-block button-link_outline" href="#">First icon</a>
  </li>
  <li class="operatorscreen__single-button">
    <a class="operatorscreen__link button-link button-block button-link_outline" href="#">Second</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're right, indeed, in my case `vertical-align: sub` centered it. But why? Could you explain? I've seen your website, seems like you're a CSS guru :)

Comment: @AlexanderKim check the update, not only sub .. top/text-top and text-bottom will also make what you want ;)

Comment: Still, top is a bit higher now :D Sub is ideal

Comment: @AlexanderKim it depend on the browser and the font and also the height of the pseudo element. change the height and you will see that even sub will not give you the middle you want ;) basically vertical align don't consider the middle of the element like you may think but there is other reference, here is a good reading if you want to get more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190413/8620333 (you can also follow the links)

Comment: thanks for explanation, too many variables there: height, font size, etc... So there's no silver bullet rule for all icons at once?

Comment: @AlexanderKim the silver and gold rule is to avoid centring using vertical-align :) .. use other stuffs like flexbox, position, etc and you will have more accurate result

Comment: Is it ok to use flexbox for icon in my case? I thought it's not a good practice.

Comment: @AlexanderKim if you use it correctly there is no issue. With flexbox you will have the dead center better than vertical align: https://jsfiddle.net/5z2qpm7v/